# The effect of over-parameterization on local minima

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, parameterization, non-convex

While reading some papers about over-parameterization in deep learning models, I also read that *"over-parametrization is a simple method to introduce additional dimensionality and help make the local minimal to be a saddle point so the optimizer would be less likely stuck at local minimal and can find the global minimal."*

My question is that how does over-parameterization and more dimensions help to make the local minima into a saddle point? I searched a lot but didn't find any proof or example that illustrates this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively (non-rigurous), a local minimum has to be a minimum for **every** point in a distance of $\epsilon$ while for an optimum to be a saddle point it just needs one direction to be different than the others. When adding parameters we are increasing the dimensionality of the function we want to minimize. After this procedure, it is less likely for a local minimum to stay a local minimum, as it would have to hold the minimum condition for all the added dimensions. Thus, adding parameters can be useful to give 'a way out' of that point which would be a local minimum in lower dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So by converting the local minima to saddle points in higher dimensional space, the optimizer can escape the saddle points easier (I read that in some papers). Do you have any intuition about why escaping saddle points is easier than escaping local minimas? Can we use the intuition of **every** direction you mentioned in this argument as well?

Comment: Without getting too technical and using the same intuition, think of a ball rolling down a mountain. If there's a local valley, a point with no slope where all directions are uphill the ball will get stuck. Now if there's another point with no slope where you facing uphill but just in certain directions the ball will be able to keep rolling down in another direction (although you will need to use an optimization algorithm which allows updating in zero slope points such as SGD).